# Why jar file imaged from Docker is corrupted?

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, jar, jenkins-cli

I downloaded the jar file (jenkins-cli.jar) using Docker using curl. Using command:

```
RUN curl --insecure -O http://192.168.99.100:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
```

This is the Dockerfile which copies the manually downloaded jar file and also file downloading.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
# Install Java.
RUN \
  echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get upgrade -y && \
  apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
  add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer

# Define commonly used JAVA_HOME variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

#Install dependencies
RUN apt-get -y update  && \
    apt-get -yqq --no-install-recommends install bash git bzip2 curl unzip && \
    apt-get update

EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /jenkins

ENV JENKINS_URL "http://192.168.99.100:8080"    
ENV PRIVATE_KEY "C:\Users\himn\.ssh\id_rsa" 
COPY jenkins-cli.jar /jenkins-cli.jar 
RUN curl -H "Accept: application/zip"  http://192.168.99.100:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar -o /opt/jenkins-cli.jar
VOLUME /ssh
ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]
```

I tried file command on both as it mentioned in comment and following is the output:
root@e31bbf40f650:/# file jenkins-cli.jar(copied jar file)
jenkins-cli.jar: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract

root@e31bbf40f650:/opt# file jenkins-cli.jar(jar file which downloaded when i build image)
jenkins-cli.jar: HTML document, ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators

Output of jenkins-ci.html using less command.

```
root@e31bbf40f650:/opt# less jenkins-ci.html
<!-- IE friendly error message walkround.
     if error message from server is less than
     512 bytes IE v5+ will use its own error
     message instead of the one returned by
     server.                                 -->






<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      html,body{
        height:100%;
        padding:0;
        margin:100;
      }
      .oc{
        display:table;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
      }
      .ic{
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
        height:100%;
      }
      div.msg{
        display:block;
        border:1px solid #30c;
        padding:0;
        width:500px;
        font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;
        margin:10px auto;
      }
      h1{
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#fff;
        font-size:14px;
        margin:0;
        padding:2px;
        text-align:center;
        background: #30c;
      }
      p{
        font-size:12px;
        margin:15px auto;
        width:75%;
        font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;
        text-align:left;
      }
    </style>
    <title>
      504 Gateway Timeout: remote server did not respond to the proxy
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="oc">
      <div class="ic">
        <div class="msg">
          <h1>
            504 Gateway Timeout: remote server did not respond to the proxy
jenkins-ci.html
```

This is my docker file which host jenkins server

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
# Install Java.
RUN \
  echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get upgrade -y && \
  apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
  add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer

# Define commonly used JAVA_HOME variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

# get maven 3.2.2 and verify its checksum
RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.2/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.tar.gz; \
echo "87e5cc81bc4ab9b83986b3e77e6b3095 /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz" | md5sum -c   
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/ven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

# install maven
RUN tar xzf /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz -C /opt/; \
  ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.2.2 /opt/maven; \
  ln -s /opt/maven/bin/mvn /usr/local/bin; \
  rm -f /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz
ENV MAVEN_HOME /opt/maven


# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get -y update  && \
    apt-get -yqq --no-install-recommends install bash git bzip2 curl unzip && \
    apt-get update

copy jenkins war file to the container
#ADD http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.107.3/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
COPY jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
ENV JENKINS_HOME /jenkins

# configure the container to run jenkins, mapping container port 8080 to that host port
RUN mkdir /jenkins/
COPY proxy.xml /jenkins/proxy.xml
COPY config_updated.xml opt/config_updated.xml

USER root
ENV JENKINS_MIRROR http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org

COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
RUN mkdir /jenkins/plugins

COPY /jenkins.war /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion


#Install plugins
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4096m"
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

COPY /plugins.sh usr/local/bin/plugins.sh
COPY /plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war"]
```

Comment: Please do not use images to show console output. You can simply copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: didt uget my problem? What else u need?

Comment: What I wrote was just a note that your image is what some may call rude because images are not covered by searches which makes it difficult to find this question - hence it may reduce the attention you get.

Comment: okey thnk u for suggestion, but that was the thing explains well about my question

Comment: @Robert's point is explained at length [in this article](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Answer (score 3):

2832 in the output of `ls` does not mean 2.83MB, it means 2832 *bytes*. I guess you should try renaming it to a filename ending in .html and open it in a web browser, or just viewing it with `less`. One of those two approaches should show you what the problem is.

Comment: Or use `file jenkins-cli.jar` to show it’s interpreted file type.

Comment: What u think? jar file is downloading or not?

Comment: It doesn't matter what I think. You need to VIEW THE CONTENTS OF THE FILE.

Comment: i used less command to check jar file, there is nothing to show in that jar file

Comment: What do you mean? Is it binary data as we would expect from a jar, or is it text or HTML? If it's text or HTML, please post the entire file.

Comment: When jar file is downloaded inside container, its packages are missing @RobinGreen why is like that and what is the best way to download properly.

Comment: and also i have observed that permission of both file is different,

Comment: Not enough information in the question. I suggest you ask a follow up question, explaining where you are getting the two files from and including your Dockerfile.

Comment: I have updated my question as u mentioned @RobinGreen

Comment: Ok so it's actually a HTML file. You need to rename it to end in .html and then view it in a browser or less.

Comment: i have tried using less command but it showing nothing, i dont want that html file. i need to download in the "jenkins-cli.jar: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract" format. How can i do it?

Comment: But you need to see what the error message in the HTML file is!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172138/discussion-between-hithesh-and-robin-green).

Comment: OK so it's a gateway timeout error. How are you downloading it outside the container?

Comment: jenkins has a option called jenkins cli, there they have provided a link, i,e http://localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar. i used the same link with my docker ip to it, it downloads the curated jar file.

Comment: https://isignal.github.io/notes/jenkins-cli.html refer this for more detail @RobinGreen

Comment: What is the IP address you are using in the URL? Is it the local IP address of your physical machine? Or something else?

Comment: its docker  ip @RobinGreen

Comment: RUN curl --insecure -O http://192.168.99.100:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar this is command i used in script to download the jar file

Comment: I think the problem is you are not starting Jenkins.

Comment: even in thought same and started jenkins using another docker image, but same result @RobinGreen

Comment: Ok please update your question to show how you are starting Jenkins

Comment: Updated as u mentioned @RobinGreen

Comment: So you are running two images side by side? They might have different IP addresses. So make sure you are using the correct IP address.

Comment: Can i set ip, so can set same ip to both dockerfile. Or can i mention ip in docker-compose(im new to it). Any way to do that pls mention or refer to it @RobinGreen